# How to show order of commits for cherry-pick

Tags: git

I am sometimes given a set of commits from a master branch which I am supposed to `cherry-pick` to our release branch. However, as the set I receive is unordered, I go through a manual process of inspecting the git log to ensure that i pick the commits in the same order as they appear on the master branch.

How can I do this with a command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t need to do anything – `git cherry-pick` will automatically apply the commits in the correct order. The order in the command line does not matter.